# Failed too many review audits - why?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I just came back from a nice vacation to find out "I failed too many review audits".
As far as I can remember, I left for my vacation with good review status (failed a few, but overall taking good care for reviewing thoroughly all posts).
I don't understand how come I get this message without failing an audit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the block is user based rather than IP based, but just to cross it off the list of possibilities... is there other SO users using your computer/ Internet connection?

Comment: You were banned from review manually by a moderator. I'll ping them to drop on by and explain why that was.

Comment: @Matt I'm pretty sure I'm the only SO user on my machine. It would be a bit creepy to learn otherwise...

Comment: @BradLarson - thank you. Is it common practice to ban someone manually without any notice/explanation? a bit impolite if you ask me...

Comment: In the current system, there is no way to notify a user about the reason for the ban, short of sending them a direct moderator message which would remain on their record permanently. Generally, a user should know exactly why they were banned from review (gaming audits, approving spam, etc.) and this acts as a nudge for them to pay more attention. I could see an argument for the addition of a feature where we provide language in the ban message that indicates what specifically we saw.

Comment: @BradLarson that would be nice, probably would have saved this post and trouble.

Comment: Note that audits aren't everything, if there are some obvious cases where you've mis-reviewed on a nonaudit post you can easily get manual banned.

Comment: @Manishearth - well I must confess I was not the best of reviewers and it's not my first ban. But I learned my lesson after my last ban and I really tried to do a good job on the reviews. So, I honestly did not see this coming, and I would like to know what i did wrong so i can do better next time.

Comment: @Shai Don't worry, there ought to be a better explanation coming up soon for this. This seems to be an edge case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was based on the audits you failed in the reopen queue. Might want to slow down a bit there.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm still a little buffled about this: shouldn't the ban come right after failing an audit? As far as I can remember I did not fail a reopen audit recently (might failed a few in the past, but also passed quite a few more...)?

Comment: One more thing: Failing an audit counts against me, but does passing an audit successfuly count for me? Don't I get some credit for passing an audit?

Comment: @Shai The automatic banning system is not nearly as good as catching potentially abusive behavior than we'd like it to be. If your reviews are audited manually by a moderator and they think a review ban is in order—even if there was no automatic ban issued—you could be banned without failing a recent audit, so to speak.

Comment: @Shog9 - Considering [some of the re-open review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197243/how-come-this-reopen-review-audit-not-re-open) might I argue that I am being treated in a bit of a harsh manner here? Would it be in place to ask to be treated with a bit more patiace in the future? Thank you.