# How come this reopen review (audit) not "re-open"?

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, vote-to-reopen, disputed-review-audits

I failed this reopen review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2941248

I clicked "reopen" and apparently I should have left the question closed.

I do not understand why: The question was closed because it was not phrased clearly, it underwent **extensive** editing by the OP.
I believe that in its current, edited, version it is a clear question now and should be given a second chance.

Can you please tell me why I am wrong here?
Why should this question be left closed even after OP's edit?
Is it such a clear-cut case that it should become an audit item?

Comment: Yes, the question was revised by the OP, but it was still deleted. Audits are meant so that you would check the actual question pages.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - I looked at the question itself, at its two versions, before and after the edit. I agree that even after the edit it will not be nominated for "question of the year" award, but I do believe its closing reason "unclear what you are asking" is no longer valid and therefore needs to be reopend.

Comment: so questions that are closed, then edited, then deleted now may become reopen audits? Now excuse me for a while, I'm going to poison the honey in the honeypot.

Comment: Who audit the audits? Are posts becoming "audits" automatically?

Comment: @Shai yes, they are, but this criterion is plain wrong.

Comment: edited question may be right on the way for undeletion and reopening; as long as system can not reliably determine whether this is the case or not (and it looks like it **can't**), picking it for audits is a design mistake

Comment: Yeah, that's not a very good question.  It's basically "troubleshoot my code for me" without any clear explanation of what the code is supposed to do.